# When i upload my csv using product-csv-import pugin getting following error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Call to undefined method WooCommerce::clear_product_transients() in /home/gorilla/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-csv-import-suite/classes/class-wc-product-import.php on line 327

Please solve my problem as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a plugin called 'WooCommerce Product CSV Import Suite', which relies on [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/). Is WooCommerce installed?